# SQLConnectionString to ORM How

Tags: .net, orm

Hi someone can help me here.

How will this code look like if using ORM connection

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Sub OpenDBproduct()
        Dim ProductConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)

        Dim ProductReader As SqlDataReader
        Dim ProductCommand As SqlCommand

        Dim ProductSQL As String = ""
        ProductSQL = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY PName DESC;"
        ProductCommand = New SqlCommand(ProductSQL, ProductConnection)

        'Prøv at åben Connection.
        Try
            ProductConnection.Open()
            ProductReader = ProductCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            'Hvis der er data, udskriv da dataen.
            If ProductReader.HasRows() Then

                Response.Write("<h2>Produkter</h2>")
                Response.Write("<table style=""width:340px; border:0px;""><tr>")

                Do While ProductReader.Read()
                    Response.Write("<td colspan=""3""><br /></td>")
                    Response.Write("</tr><tr>")
                    Response.Write("<td style=""width:10px;""></td>")
                    Response.Write("<td><div style=""width:52px; text-align:center;""><span class=""""># " & ProductReader("PName") & "</span></div></td>")
                    Response.Write("<td class=""""><span class="""">" & ProductReader("PName") & "</span><br /><span class="""">" & ProductReader("PPrice") & "</span><br /><span class=""""><b>" & ProductReader("Pean") & "</b></span></td>")
                    Response.Write("</tr><tr>")
                    Response.Write("<td colspan=""3""><br />" & ProductReader("PDescription") & "</td>")
                    Response.Write("</tr><tr>")
                    Response.Write("<td style=""border-bottom:dashed 2px #FFA902;"" colspan=""3""><br /></td>")
                    Response.Write("</tr><tr>")

                Loop
                Response.Write("</tr></table>")
                Response.Write("Slutning")
            Else
                'Hvis der ikke er data, lav en fejl tekst.
                Response.Write("<table style=""width:340px; border:0px;""><tr><td>")
                Response.Write("Der findes ingen produkter.")
                Response.Write("<br /><br />")
                Response.Write("Slutning")
                Response.Write("</td></tr></table>")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)

        Finally
            'Lukker Connection, Reader og Sletter Hukommelse.
            If Not ProductReader Is Nothing Then
                ProductReader.Dispose()
            End If
            If Not ProductConnection Is Nothing Then
                ProductConnection.Dispose()
            End If

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'm thinking he means a LINQ to SQL DataContext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right - you ask about changes no that code if you use some ORM, like EntityFramework or NHibernate.
So short description is (sorry for C# syntax):
connecting will change to **strongly typed** code, without SQL string.

```
using (var dbContext = new ProductEntites())
{
   var dbSelect = dbContext.Products.OrderBy(x=>x.PName);
```

Do-While will be changed to `foreach(var product in dbSelect)`

All `ProductReader("PDescription")` would be changed to `product.PDescription` (no strings!)

Using ORM

- it's much safer to use all profits of strongly typed classes (they will be generated with Visual Studio tools)
- parameter checks for SQL-injections are mede automatically
- is highly recommended if you need to create DB-independant application

Comment: Hi thx, but im not working with this daily, so hope that someone will give me an ec. out from my code so i can see what part do what.